# KSQLDB Cluster persistent error on a number of queries sometimes

Tags: ksqldb

I have a ksqldbcluster with 2 nodes. Sometimes i might receive an alert from grafana(which i monitor the cluster) that some queries are in error state. When i check the show queries i see that a number of queries have 1 PERSISTENT running and 1 ERROR. I restart first the second ksqdb docker instance. Sometimes is fixed sometimes is not. If is not i restart the first ksqldb docker instance and then is fixed. Any ideas?

> version: '3' services:   ksqldb-server:
> container_name: ksqldb-server
> hostname: ksqldb.xxxxxxx
> network_mode: host
> image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server:latest
> environment:
> KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb.xxxxxxxx
> KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: xxxxxx:9093
> KSQL_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SSL
> KSQL_LISTENERS: http://xxxxxx:8088,https://xxxxxx:8443
> KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://xxxxxxxx-as.net:8081,http://xxxxxx:8082
> KSQL_SSL_CLIENT_KEY_STORE_LOCATION: /etc/kafka/secrets/ksqldb.keystore.jks
> KSQL_SSL_CLIENT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD: xxxxxx
> KSQL_SSL_CLIENT_TRUST_STORE_LOCATION: /etc/kafka/secrets/ksqldb.keystore.jks
> KSQL_SSL_CLIENT_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD: xxxxxxx
> KSQL_SERVER_ID: id1
> KSQL_STREAMS_NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS: 1  # Corrected property name
> KSQL_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "ERROR"
> KSQL_QUERY_PULL_ENABLE_STANDBY_READS: true
> KSQL_HEARTBEAT_ENABLE: true
> KSQL_QUERY_PULL_THREAD_POOL_SIZE: "30"
> KSQL_LAG_REPORTING_ENABLE: true
> KSQL_INTERNAL_LISTENER: http://xxxxxxx:8080
> KSQL_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /etc/kafka/secrets/ksqldb.truststore.jks
> KSQL_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: xxxxxx
> KSQL_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION: /etc/kafka/secrets/ksqldb.keystore.jks
> KSQL_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: xxxxxxx
> KSQL_JMX_OPTS: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -javaagent:/etc/kafka/secrets/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.17.2.jar=4000:/etc/kafka/secrets/ksql.yaml
> ports:
> - 8088:8088
> - 4000:4000
> - 8443:8443
> volumes:
> - /ksqldata/data:/var/lib/ksqldb-server/data
> - /ksqldata/newssl/:/etc/kafka/secrets/
>
> ksqldb-cli:
> image: confluentinc/ksqldb-cli:latest
> container_name: ksqldb-cli
> entrypoint: /bin/sh
> tty: true  # Corrected indentation
>
> telegraf:
> image: telegraf
> restart: always
> volumes:
> - ./telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro
> - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ~

When  restarting ksqldb instance the issue is resolved. Maybe i am missing something in my parameters or how to fix the error?